# Finding maximum and minimum in vector of custom data using algorithm

Tags: c++, c++11, stl-algorithm

I have a data structure like this:

```
struct Speed {

       int set; //set by user
       int act; //actual speed
       int millis; //millis since epoch
}

vector<Speed> data;
```

Now I want to draw this vector. To create a nice axis, I want to find the max and min of data in this vector. I do like this but obviously, since it is based only on `set`, it will fail me if at any point `act` is smaller or larger than `set`. I mean the `Y` axis of the chart should be between minimum of `set, act` and maximum of `set, act`.

```
auto max = std::max_element(begin(data), end(data),
                            [&](const Speed& a, const Speed& b){
    return a.set() < b.set(); 
    //how about act?
});

auto min = std::min_element(begin(data), end(data),
                            [&](const Speed& a, const Speed& b){
    return a.set() < b.set();
    //how about act?
});
```

**I KNOW ** how to write a normal code not involving algorithm and lambdas to achieve the result...but I am interested to see how it is possible to do with algorithm/lambda WITHOUT having operator overloading in the structure.

I could also do the same for `act` then compare results...but that would cost me 4 loops!

Comment: It's unclear how you want the comparison to act? You want the smallest/largest of set and act? The average? The min/max of the sum of set and act? There are a lot of ways to compare two values.

Comment: @Jonesinator I just want to get min and max for my chart to cover both values ranges

Comment: Is your question about constructing a comparison function for two properties (set , act) ?

Comment: Do you want the min/max elements w.r.t set and also the min/max elements w.r.t act, or the min/max elements w.r.t to both set **and** act?

Comment: @Daniel w.r.t both of course!

Comment: but you are aware of the fact that `max/min_element` returns an iterator to one of the element of the collection?

Comment: Obviously, you cannot return 2 values from the same call to `std::min_element`... But you could get both min and max in a single loop with `std::minmax_element`.

Comment: @W.F. yes, so I want it to get for the item wich has the max between set and act, and another one for min between set and act

Comment: @SaeidYazdani oh that made it clearer... see an answer of the Jonesinator cause it might be what you want

Comment: @SaeidYazdani You should write a clear question from the start. **This question is very poorly written**. Make the effort of asking good question. If you are not good at asking question, then should an example or two of input data and desired output.

Comment: @Phil1970 you are right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, I would recommend most readable code.

Thus, it would be something like (assuming at least one item):

```
auto set_minmax = std::minmax_element(begin(data), end(data),
    [&](const Speed& a, const Speed& b) { return a.set < b.set; });

auto act_minmax = std::minmax_element(begin(data), end(data),
    [&](const Speed& a, const Speed& b) { return a.act < b.act; });

auto min_act_set = std::min(*set_minmax.first, *act_minmax.first);
auto max_act_set = std::max(*set_minmax.second, *act_minmax.second);
```

However, if the data is really big or the logic is more complex, I would recommend to have an object that accumulate statistics and do some kind of loop over the data.

Comment: I indeed ended up using my own loop because otherwise I would possibly get 2x the calls to get a value (with two shared pointers) instead of one in my loop. Small optimization, but over time, that's still quite a bit of cycles saved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::min` and `std::max` inside of your `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` invocations.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Speed {
       int set;
       int act;
       int millis;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Speed> data = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}
    };

    auto max_val = std::max_element(begin(data), end(data),
                                    [](const Speed& a, const Speed& b){
        return std::max(a.set, a.act) < std::max(b.set, b.act);
    });

    auto min_val = std::min_element(begin(data), end(data),
                                    [](const Speed& a, const Speed& b){
        return std::min(a.set, a.act) < std::min(b.set, b.act);
    });

    std::cout << "MAX: " << max_val->set << " " << max_val->act << "\n";
    std::cout << "MIN: " << min_val->set << " " << min_val->act << "\n";
}
```

A single pass with `std::minmax` can't really work here. Each comparison of elements must return a boolean where `true` means the left-hand side is less-than the right-hand side and `false` means the the left-hand side is greater-than or equal-to the right-hand side (i.e. a strict weak ordering is required). However, here a single element can both be less-than *and* greater-than another element. You could easily write your own function to make a single-pass minmax_element, but I don't think it fits nicely into the existing STL functions without making two passes.

Comment: If this is what OP wants as a result, then I would use `std::minmax_element` for each members then afterward get final minimum and maximum. Probably easier to read and more efficient.

Comment: With some changes https://onlinegdb.com/SJZCyXKhb  it is close to what I meant...but would be nice if this can be done in only one loop

Comment: I think that the one loop approach won't properly handle all cases. For example, would it works if the same item is both the minimum for one field and the maximum for the other field.

Comment: Yeah, actually @Phil1970 is right, the `std::minmax_element` implementation doesn't work for all cases.

Comment: yep it failed for some cases!